# Query to select data from mysql with specific condition

Tags: mysql

In MySQL we can use this code to select rows with ID numbers (or anything else) between a list:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE prophrases IN (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Thats OK! but if we need to search a number in a Field's value, what we can do?
For example, I have a table with a field, named '*prophases*' and I saved data like this:

rowid / prophases

1          / 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

2          / 6,5,2,7,9,2

now, i need to check if a number like 6 is in prophrases in row #1 or not!
what can i do for that?

something like this but in correct form!

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE 6 IN prophrases
```

Comment: Don't save your data like this

Comment: You don't have to use an RDBMS. But, if you are going to, then you should consider using one properly. Otherwise, what's the point?

Comment: Use `LIKE` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-like/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work if you are only dealing with single digits

```
    select * from tablename where prophrases like '%6%'
```

This will work if you are going to have number with more than one digit and there are no spaces between commas.

```
    select * from tablename where prophrases like '%,6,%' or prophrases like '6,%' or prophrases like '%,6'
```

Comment: why would you do it this way? this is slow

Comment: Well i would set my table structure up different if I were doing this. I was not aware of the FIND_IN_SET() function. Good to know thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you should just use [**FIND_IN_SET()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT rowid
FROM TABLENAME
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('6', prophrases)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a like statement

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE prophrases LIKE '%6%'
```

However if you have multiple digit numbers that could cause some unexpected results, so you might have to amend it like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE prophrases LIKE '%,6,%' 
OR prophrases LIKE '6,%' 
OR prophrases LIKE '%,6'
```

The first part matches 6 in between commas, the second one matches a 6 at the beginning followed by a comma, the third matches a comma followed by a six a the end.

Storing data like that is not the best way of doing it.  You are probably better off having another table that has a one-to-many relationship.